# Padé approximation to a nonlinear first order complex ode

Tags: approximation

I wish to approximate the following ode with Padé:

$$\dot \rho  +i\frac{{\hat \sigma }}{2}\rho  + i\alpha \rho \left[ { - {\gamma ^2} + \frac{{{\gamma ^3}}}{{\sqrt {{\gamma ^2} + 1} }}} \right] + i\frac{{\hat P}}{4}{\rho ^*} = 0$$

where $$\rho(t)$$ is a complex function of time and $$[~\gamma=\frac{1}{{\sqrt \beta  \left| \rho  \right|}}$$
$$\beta,$$$$\alpha,$$$$\hat \sigma,$$$$\hat P~]$$ are constants.

I developed Taylor's series about zero but I get a very inconvenient expression.
How one can transform the ode into a convenient from before expanding to Taylor's?

Comment: Transform the ODE or the Taylor series solution ?

Comment: I wish to get Pade approximants. But first I wish to apply Taylor series to the ode